# Swapping Option and Command keys (emacs-style) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, emacs

Choosing the emacs key bindings in Eclipse on OS X is nice, but the
Option and Command keys need to be swapped to be convenient.

This is a problem in emacs itself under OS X. The solution under emacs is
easy. (Look under *Mac OS X* in [Meta-key problems](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems#toc15).)

How do I swap Option and Command after choosing the emacs keybindings
under Eclipse (without doing it one-by-one, that is)?

Answer (score 0):

You can swap these keys globally in “System Preferences”, “Keyboard”, “Keyboard” tab, “Modifier keys…”.  I do not know any solution specific to Eclipse.

You may also want to look at [emacs-eclim](https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim), which makes Eclipse commands available within Emacs.

Comment: This messes up OSX. For example, I'd like command-tab to continue to switch between programs, yet I'd like command-d to delete the current word within Eclipse. That is why I found it is best to leave OSX alone and swap the option and command in ~/.emacs.